# Welcome windows of Android studio missing options (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, android-studio

I installed the android studio on ubuntu 20.04 and "create new project" is missing in the "Welcome to Android Studio" window.
Android studio is working fine but in order to create a new project I need to have one already open and create it from the android studio ide.
Is this normal or a bug?

[Welcome to Android Studio window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVEot.png)

I already tried to reinstall and install it in a virtual machine and this happens every time.